# MSAL : Issue with acquire token slently

Tags: angular, angular8, azure-ad-msal

Hi I am using "MSAL" library in angular. When i try to acquire token silently i get the old token in the response.

```
if (this.authService.getAccount()) {
    this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(this.loginRequest)
                            .then((response: AuthResponse) => {
    });
}
```

In the above code when i check the response in that i get the expired token. But when i debug the "this. authService" i see the new token in redirect response. What could be that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `authService` cache? Can you find in it's documentation how to clear that cache?

Comment: How are you verifying that the token returned is expired?

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample documentation here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/4b74fda49768168768ed427609941566e41456d3/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md#token-renewal

acquireTokenSilent in theory would always return a valid token, based on the documentation. It will always get from cache first if available then if expired it will request new token using refresh token and if that fails it will try to request through an iframe.

If I were to guess, it has something to do with your object instantiation in JavaScript if something is going funny, but not sure since I only see the little snippet.

I would try to match your code a bit closer to the sample, and see if you have the same issue if possible.

Comment: You can consider looking at the following angular sample as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=angular